# UITextView space character issue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitextview, space, trim

I am having trouble appending space to my UITextView.

```
self.textview.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ ", self.textview.text];
//or
NSString *myStr = @"Hello!";
myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ ", myStr];
self.textview.text = myStr;
//Result should be: Hello! <-With space here after the end of it.
```

How can I go about appending space to my UITextView? Neither of these methods work. The space seems to disappear in my textview as if it were being trimmed.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work because you don't see the space being printed, right?

Comment: That's right. The space doesn't even show up on the textview.

Answer (score 0):

### Resolution of the problem described below: my issue was fixed with the Mavericks/Xcode 5.0.1 update. It appears this was a SDK bug.

I'm having what looks like the exact same problem in a terminal app - when I hit space (e.g. to read text on a remote site that is displaying with `more`) I get a crash because the textfield has no space character and therefore the range is out of bounds. (See below for the code where this happens)

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    return NO;
}
```

This just keeps the textview focused and handling all the keys pressed. It's my way of grabbing keyboard characters one by one to send over the telnet client.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

  NSLog(@"—%@— is replacementText", text);
  return YES;
}
```

I see `xterminal[37918:c07] — — is replacementText` as soon as space is tapped. I didn't have this when I discovered the problem - it was added to be sure that a space was being seen by the UITextView.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    // determine whether the key was a backspace
    if([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        uint8_t bsValue = kTelnetCharBS;
        [connection sendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&bsValue length:1]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"—%@— in output buffer", textView.text);

        // Not a backspace, send all but the 'X'
        NSRange allButX = NSMakeRange(1, 1);
        [connection sendString:[textView.text substringWithRange:allButX]];
    }
    textView.text = @"X";
}
```

I see `xterminal[37918:c07] —X— in output buffer`

immediately after, and a crash at

`[connection sendString:[textView.text substringWithRange:allButX]];`

The space isn't there or `NSRange allButX = NSMakeRange(1, 1);` would be OK as it is with other printable characters.

There are no other delegate methods of the UITextView implemented. It is created with

```
inputTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

and immediately after

```
inputTextView.text = @"X";
inputTextView.delegate = self;
inputTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[self.view addSubview:inputTextView];
[inputTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Where's my space?

Update: Still no idea why UITextView behaves as it does. UITextField works the way I want, created the same way. To replace the UITextView delegate method `textViewDidChange:` I'm using this:

```
[inputTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Same code otherwise.